# How to make a bold header in a Prawn table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prawn, prawnto

I'm using Prawn and need to make the Header row bold but I can't find any solution in the API.

Here you can see my current table with normal text Headers

```
pdf.table (Data, :header => true) do
  table.header=(["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"])        
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its just as simple as I thought

```
pdf.table Data, {:header => true} do |table|
    table.header=(["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"])     
    table.row(0).font_style = :bold
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf.text "your header.", :size => 9.8, :style => :bold, :spacing => 1.5, :align => :right
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf.table(
  data, 
  :headers => [
    "Header1", 
    {:text => "Header2", :font_size => :bold}, 
    "Header3", 
    "Header4"]
)
```

other options:

:align_headers
:header_text_color
:header_color

see
http://rubydoc.info/gems/prawn-layout/0.8.4/Prawn/Table